# Historical examples of "pseudoscience" becoming "science"

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

What are some historical examples of theories/ideas that were initially labeled "pseudoscience" and later considered legitimate "science"? I don't mean theories or ideas that were initially not accepted or ignored and later accepted, but things that were derided as pseudoscientific (and labeled as such) but then either evidence or new theories eventually made them considered "science." Something akin to the hypothetical where "dowsing" was suddenly given a mechanistic and experimental basis that convinced the scientific community to accept it as "real science" (or similarly for parapsychic powers).

Comment: I seem to recall that plate tectonics was once considered pseudoscience and is now accepted as established science.

Comment: Is there a time range for this? Distinctions between pseudoscience and science are a 20th century creation, so the question is not very sound historically. There was no sharp separation between alchemy and chemistry or astrology and astronomy before mid 18th century, for example, see [Secrets of Nature: Astrology and Alchemy in Early Modern Europe](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/39762) volume.

Comment: This isn't a valid question because "pseudoscience" is a nonword, like "fake news" or "alternative medicine."   Now, if you want examples of valid research which took a long time to be accepted, consider plate tectonics,  ulcers and rotavirus, or even cleanliness and reduced maternal childbirth death.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it's perfectly valid. I am asking for historical examples when people were accused of their work/experiments/theories being 'not science' (or called explicitly 'pseudoscience') and it later becoming accepted as science/part of consensus. If you read my question, I specifically said I am not looking for examples of theories that were not accepted (but not disputed as "not science"). (Conifold: any time range with the caveat that the label "pseudoscience" was coined at a specific point like you said)

Comment: Then your question is even less reasonable.   There are far too many anti-science people (and there have been far too many of them in the past) to give any value to shouts of "pseudoscience"  against any nascent theory.

Comment: Copernicus and his later proven heliocentric model of the solar system.

Comment: Germ theory. Creator was killed in an insane asylum

Comment: FWIW, the opposite has been somewhat common. For example, homeopathy was at one time hailed as an amazing scientific breakthrough in medicine, but by the middle of the 20th century it was determined that homeopathy actually performed little better than placebo and that the supposed effect was because "mainstream" medicine of the 19th century was even *more* unscientific, ignored evidence in favor of dogmatism, and used many dangerous treatments that killed patients who would have lived with no treatment.

Comment: See also this question: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/8184/229

Comment: I don't recall all the details enough to make a properly informed answer (hence this comment), but the asteroid-impact theory of dinosaur extinction had a hostile reception by paleontologists for a long time. Part of why they didn't like it was because the main proponent (Alvarez) was a physicist who trusted the math of orbital mechanics more than the paleontologists' longstanding (and somewhat justified) bias against catastrophism. It was one of those academic turf-war things. "Heroic outsider overturns fusty dogma" is a common narrative for pseudoscience believers; but here it was real.

Comment: This question reminds me of the quote a technology sufficiently advanced should be indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: It is a valid and clear question!!

Answer (score 15):

For a long while it was widely believed that the main cause of peptic ulcer disease was stress or spicy food. When the theory arose that it was in fact usually an infection this was rejected by the medical establishment. The Greek physician [John Lykoudis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Lykoudis) was in fact fined for his treatment of patients with antibiotics. Subsequent work by Australian scientists identified the bacterium responsible *Helicobacter pylori* and they were awarded the Nobel for their work. A [full timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_peptic_ulcer_disease_and_Helicobacter_pylori) is available on Wikipedia. It is far too long to summarise here.

Comment: The most spectacular episode of that controversy was when Dr Barry Marshall intentionally swallowed a disgusting concoction of H. pylori bacteria. He promptly developed nasty stomach ulcers. Then he took antibiotics to cure them. He really earned that Nobel Prize.

Comment: @dain: Sounds like a case worthy of the snopes treatment...

Answer (score 11):

*copied from my answer to [another question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/8188/229)

It seems **ball lightning** was disbelieved by scientists until around 1960.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning) .

I knew a geologist who told us how his eye-witness account of ball lightning had been ridiculed.  He had learned not to mention it when he interviewed for jobs as a professor of geology.

Answer (score 9):

**Plate tectonics**

It was put forth by a *meterologist*, and offered no explanation how, given the solid crust and mantle, the continents could drift about like icebergs on the liquid core.

The discovery of processes by which a solid surface could indeed drift about took decades, but finally triumphed.

Answer (score 7):

The **germ theory of disease**, and in general **the importance of handwashing** was a fringe viewpoint for a long time. Good evidence existed since at least the early 19th century that micro-organisms could cause disease, but the medical profession was very slow on the uptake.

Dr Semmelweis, though he lacked any theoretical model, saved the lives of many mothers and newborns by his insistence on handwashing in his maternity ward. Despite strong empirical evidence, the scientific community largely hated his ideas, and the acrimony led to the poor doctor suffering a nervous breakdown and premature death.

Answer (score 5):

I have an impression that until about 1800 scientists did not believe that rocks could fall from the sky, but I don't have a better source than the [following](https://artsandculture.google.com/story/the-sky-is-falling-meteors-and-meteorites-through-history-adler-planetarium/vgWh-qne7tsiIw?hl=en):

> Reports of fireballs accompanied by the fall of iron or stony objects
> go back to ancient times, and some of those objects were kept and
> thought of as sacred. But by the 18th century, scholars remained
> generally dismissive of popular accounts of such events, deeming them
> fanciful and as expressions of superstition and ignorance. By the turn
> of the 19th century, with a growing number of reports on fireballs
> accompanied by falling stones from various parts of the world, they
> started to change their minds.

Comment: what is super interesting to me is that at least one guy, decades before nuclear energy was understood, suggested that the sun was powered by such rocks falling into it. While that sound crazy, without understanding fusion/fission, the vast output of the sun was unexplainable.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics, infinitesimals were widely considered not merely "pseudoscience" but "chimeras", "hallucinations", "cholera bacilli", "fantasies", "abominations", "debasement of meaning", "hazy mist", "empty words", and what not, and altogether an intellectual embarassment to shun as a plague.  One of the major objections was of theological origin; see [this publication](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/infinitesimals.html#18d).

This went on for hundreds of years until in the second half of the 20th century, serviceable theories of infinitesimals were finally developed.  A vigorous debate continues until this day, including a recent lively exchange in the pages of *The Mathematical Intelligencer*.

Comment: there are many people today who question the existence of mathematical objects that most of use without question. one mathematician that I have listened to does not "believe" in irrational numbers. He knows about them but he's "never seen one."

Comment: It would be hard to do geometry without a number corresponding to the length of the diagonal of the unit square, and without a number corresponding to the length of the unit circle. @releseabe

Answer (score 1):

The "golden" age of alchemy was about 1300–1700 BCE and was replaced by more empirically based chemistry. Alchemists dreamed of finding the philosopher's stone, a material that would transform other metals into gold, but it was based in occultism and mysticism.

We had to wait until the 20th century to show that (nuclear) **transmutation** is actually possible via relativistic quantum mechanical effects. Some elements (like bismuth, platinum or mercury) can be now transmuted into gold either by gamma or neutron scattering experiments (experiments that are more expensive than the quantities of gold produced). Also some elements naturally decay into gold (after a very very long time).

Answer (score -1):

It is somewhat astonishing that a phenomenon  that was commonly thought of as belonging to the realm of parapsychology or superstition, has become an object of scientific investigation and its existence has been  increasingly accepted as possible in  scientific environments.

I refer to **telepathy**:  nowadays,  a sound and serious scientific research in the field is carried on, also by universities as MIT, Harvard  and Washington University. These new researches  suggest that some forms of telepathy are possible.

Of course, we are not speaking of telepathy as told  by parapsychologists or occultism, as folding a fork with the force of the mind or voluntary  communicating with another person with the force of thought,  and of course not reproducible in everyday life.

But the scientific world has been increasingly aware that some forms of communication between ‘brains’ are possible.

A forerunner of neuroscience in regarding telepathy not as a superstition but an actual phenomenon, deserving attention even if not understood, can be considered psychoanalysis.

It is enough well known that telepathy is a phenomenon that has been regarded,  for  many years,   not as paranormal or pseudo- scientific by serious communities as Freudian societies: the Freudian societies are  deemed as the more ‘scientific’ and rigorous psychoanalytic communities, not at all inclined to accept fancy or imaginative phenomena.

Freud itself paid attention to telepathy and to which he called ‘unconscious communication’ mainly in two works, *Psychoanalysis and Telepathy* and *Dream and telepathy*, both written in 1921.

A controversial debate took place in those years about the matter, in particular there was a
disagreement with Ernest Jones,  about  the explicit ‘resistance’ of Freud and other psychoanalysts towards  extrasensory phenomena. And a general tendency to ignore these phenomena  followed in subsequent years .

But Freud kept alive his long-standing   curiosity toward the transmission of thought and extrasensory phenomena,  as witnessed for instance by several essays he devoted to dreams and occultism in the period 1921-1932.   Freud states clearly that he is very skeptical about supernatural phenomena,  but at the same time his attitude became more positive, particularly toward telepathy.

In psychoanalytic communities, in more recent times, has been increasingly accepted that some experiences of telepathy, not explained but frequently observed, occur  in  psychoanalytical  clinical context,   where some strange, unexpected,  ‘telepathic’ phenomena manifest themselves (mainly in dreams), in which someone guesses some thought or some aspect of the life of another person, without any apparent information about them. For examples of papers about this subject see (1).

If  psychoanalysis can be considered science or not is subject of discussion. But, of course, these are  not scientific investigations in the sense of ‘hard sciences’ as commonly understood.

But, nowadays , the possibility of telepathy isn't any longer  considered an irrational and fancy hypothesis also by ‘harder’ scientists as neuroscientists. It  is viewed as a possible field of research in neurosciences  about the functioning of the human brain,  about  which  we don’t still know very much.

This is a recent news by BBC:

> **Scientists 'make telepathy breakthrough'**
>
> Research led by experts at Harvard University shows technology can be used to send a simple mental message from one person to another without any contact between the two.
> Neuroscientist Giulio Ruffini told the Today programme: "You can actually transmit information directly from one brain to another brain without intervention of the senses."
> "The next step would be to try to find more powerful techniques to send more complex >information," he added.

https://www.bbc.com/news/av/science-environment-29093700

Below an article on the matter of a serious and well-known Italian review of scientific dissemination, *Focus*. I translate the beginning of the article of *Focus*,

From *Focus*:

> **Is telepathy scientifically  possible?**
>
> *Not exactly as in movies, but something similar to telepathy exists.
> And research is making progress.*
>
> In scientific terms, we speak of brain-to-brain communication, and
> some experiments of recent years prove that it is possible to put in
> connection brains of several individual through a ‘computerized  neural
> interface’, called BCI ( brain-computer interface). This instrument registers, encodes and decodes electrical impulses, which can be transmitted by radio, wi-fi, internet and so on.

https://www.focus.it/scienza/scienze/la-telepatia-e-scientificamente-possibile

Other related links, from MIT,  are:

https://www.technologyreview.com/2014/11/21/170337/are-telepathy-experiments-stunts-or-science/

https://massivesci.com/articles/mind-control-brain-machine-interface/

In short, therefore, we can say that telepathy is in progress of being carried from pseudoscience to science, even if it seems, as far as I know,  that research in the field is still at its beginning.

---

(1) For examples of books and papers  about telepathy and psychoanalysis :

https://www.amazon.it/Sigmund-Freud-Forsyth-Case-Thought-Transmission/dp/1032159588/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=7KZZDYY2O7CV&keywords=maria+pierri+telepathy&qid=1672672827&s=books&sprefix=maria+pierri+telepathy%2Cstripbooks%2C147&sr=1-2

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6853049/

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10481885.2014.870841

https://www.torrossa.com/it/resources/an/4312142

This last paper is by some of the most prominent and appreciated Italian psychoanalysts.

Comment: I want to point out that what I wrote is perfectly scientific and well known in wide intellectual and scientific communities in many countries, for a few decades, it isn't a new matter. And there are, as I show, papers on the subjet published in many  important journals and universities, not at all 'antiscientific'. What is science and what is pseudo-science cannot established by me or someone else, but the only possible criterion here is the acceptance by intellectual and scientific communities, and now thelepaty is object of serious investigation, it is a fact, and a well known fact.

Comment: In this site we are talking of hystory and social hystory of science, and what I described is what happened in scientific communities.  History  is  not a matter of opinions, or of believing or not believing to thelepathy, but history must  report the actual facts of science and what happens in scientific communities, without prejudice and subjective judgments.