What are some examples of fringe science theories from the past that are widely accepted today?
Throughout history, many scientific theories that were initially considered fringe or controversial have eventually become widely accepted within the scientific community.
These ideas often faced skepticism and resistance before gaining acknowledgment as scientific contributions. What are some examples of such theories?

See also https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7642/229

Totally it does!
